# Submit CGridView Checked values using a form

Tags: php, forms, yii

I have a CGridView wigdet with CCheckBoxColumn like this:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'columns'=>array(
        array(
            'class'=>'CCheckBoxColumn',
        ),
        'title',
        ....
    ),
));
```

Question: how to submit to controller action the checked values? I understand that I need a form, submit button, but I need a clear explanation where to put things, so that search boxes on the top appear.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you want to use ajax?

Comment: @bool.dev not necessarily; search - that's what I want, so that user can search, check, and submit.

Comment: ok, and what are you expecting in the controller? just the checked records' id(s)? or also the search parameters? don't think search parameters are necessary, btw.

Comment: have you tried my solution below?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not absolutely need another form. You can just use a link with additional javascript attached to it.

To get the checked values, you can call the javascript function `$.fn.yiiGridView.getChecked(containerID,columnID)`, see [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CCheckBoxColumn#selectableRows-detail), it returns an array containing the ids.

#### Full example (with ajax):

In your view:

```
<?php
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
   'id'=>'example-grid-view-id', // the containerID for getChecked
   'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
   'columns'=>array(
       array(
           'class'=>'CCheckBoxColumn',
           'id'=>'example-check-boxes' // the columnID for getChecked
       ),
       'title',
       ....
   ),
));
?>
<div id="for-link">
<?php
   echo CHtml::ajaxLink('SomeLink',Yii::app->createUrl('somecontroller/someaction'),
        array(
           'type'=>'POST',
           'data'=>'js:{theIds : $.fn.yiiGridView.getChecked("example-grid-view-id","example-check-boxes").toString()}'
           // pay special attention to how the data is passed here
        )
   );
?>
<div>
```

In your controller:

```
...
public function actionSomeaction(){
    if(isset($_POST['theIds'])){
          $arra=explode(',', $_POST['theIds']);
          // now do something with the ids in $arra
          ...
    }
    ...
}
...
```

You could also use json string, instead of simple string, in the data we pass by ajax (from the view), but then instead of `explode()`, you would use `json_decode()` (in the controller). Also it would be better to validate/sanitize the ids before use.

Check out the documentation for [CHtml::ajaxLink](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#ajaxLink-detail) to know more about ajax links.

Note that the example is a little crude, since i haven't put in checks for empty array of checked ids.

Comment: I haven't checked your solution, since I've already done it different way, without using checkboxes :) but I like your solution very much! Thanks for detailed explanation!

Answer (score 1):

This one works with CSRF protection and updates the GridView.

```
<?php
echo CHtml::ajaxLink('ClickMe',Yii::app()->createUrl('controller/action'),
array(
'type'=>'POST',
'data'=>'js:{"ids" : $.fn.yiiGridView.getChecked("grid_view_id","check_box_id").toString(),"YII_CSRF_TOKEN" : "'.Yii::app()->request->csrfToken.'"}',
'success'=>"$('#grid_view_id').yiiGridView.update('grid_view_id')"
));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap your Gridview into a simple form you can send the checkboxs selected to the value,

An example:

**View**

```
<form id="frmSubmit">
<?php
echo CHtml::dropDownList('user_id'
        , null
        , CHtml::listData(User::model()->findAll(), 'USER_ID', 'FULLNAME')
);

echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton('Save'
                            , Yii::app()->createUrl('query/ajaxUpdate')
                            , array('success' => 'js:reloadGrid', )
                            , array('class' => 'btn btn-success'));

$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'query-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
        array(
            'id' => 'query',
            'class'=>'CCheckBoxColumn',
            'selectableRows' => '2',
        ),
        'Contact',
        'Email',
        'Company',
    ),
)); ?>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function reloadGrid(data) {
    $.fn.yiiGridView.update('query-grid');
}
</script>
```

**Controller**

```
public function actionAjaxUpdate()
{
    var_dump($_POST);
}
```