# How to process selected rows in Yii CGridView?

Tags: gridview, checkbox, yii

I have a CGridView with a CCheckBoxColumn and selectableRows = 2.  Users can select multiple rows of my grid view.

The gridview is for a list of unapproved comments and I want to be able to select comments to approve, hit an "Approve" button and update a field in the comments table for each comment that was approved.

How can I do this?

I'm open to an ajax solution but really what I want to know is how to get the list of comment ids inside my controller action code with a normal post.  I'd prefer a solution that doesn't involve javascript unless that is the only option.

Comment: for a javascript/ajax solution see: [Submit CGridView Checked values using a form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10083616/submit-cgridview-checked-values-using-a-form)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I was able to get this working without depending on javascript.  The steps are as follows:

***Add a form to your view file***

This will allow the checkbox values, which are html input elements, to be posted to your controller.

```
<?php echo CHtml::beginForm(); ?>

<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'selectableRows' => 2,
    'columns' => array(
        array(
            'id' => 'selectedIds',
            'class' => 'CCheckBoxColumn'
        ),
        'id',
        'username',
        'content',
        array(
            'name' => 'created',
            'value' => '$data->created'
        ),
    ), 
));
?>

<div>
<?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Approve', array('name' => 'ApproveButton')); ?>
<?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Delete', 
array('name' => 'DeleteButton',
'confirm' => 'Are you sure you want to permanently delete these comments?'));
?>
</div>

<?php echo CHtml::endForm(); ?>
```

Note by passing in a "Name" option to the submitButton it allows to know which button was clicked in the controller.

***Give your check box column an id***

Previously I had:

```
'columns' => array(
    array(
        'class' => 'CCheckBoxColumn'
    ),
```

I changed this to:

```
'columns' => array(
    array(
        'id' => 'selectedIds',
        'class' => 'CCheckBoxColumn'
    ),
```

Now you can reference your selected rows as an array via `$_POST['selectedIds']`.  By default the `CCheckBoxColumn` will use the primary key of your model items in the gridview (but you can change this), so selectedIds will be an array of the selected primary keys.

***Modify controller to process the selected rows***

```
public function actionApprove()
{
    if (isset($_POST['ApproveButton']))
    {
        if (isset($_POST['selectedIds']))
        {
            foreach ($_POST['selectedIds'] as $id)
            {
                $comment = $this->loadModel($id);
                $comment->is_published = 1;
                $comment->update(array('is_published'));
            }
        }
    }

    // similar code for delete button goes here

    $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
    $criteria->condition = 'is_published = 0';
    $criteria->order = 'created DESC';

    $dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('Comment');
    $dataProvider->criteria = $criteria;

    $this->render('approve', array(
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ));
}
```

I used this Yii wiki article to help me come up with this solution: [Working with CGridView in Admin Panel](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/353/working-with-cgridview-in-admin-panel/)

Not sure if this is the ideal way to do it but it works.  I'm open to suggestions for improvement or other methods.

Comment: Where I think this answer could be improved is having it use a form model.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView#selectableRows-detail) :

*A selected row will have a CSS class named 'selected'. You may also call the JavaScript function $.fn.yiiGridView.getSelection(containerID) to retrieve the key values of the selected rows.*

So i guess JS is only way to go in your case.

Comment: can you please tell where i have to put this function ?