# working with CCheckboxcolumn

Tags: yii

im new in with yii.

I'm using CGridView with a CCheckBoxColumn to select records but i don't know how to execute an action for all the checked records only. any ideas? i tried before but when i click the submit button, all rows including the one not selected are processed.

this is my coding in admin page:

```
array(
       'id'=>'check-boxes',
       'name'=>'check-boxes',
       'class'=>'CCheckBoxColumn',
       'selectableRows' => '50',  
       'checked'=>"0",
    ),
```

i dont know how to post the checkbox value and everytime i post it, it give value of check-box[].

i submit it using this coding:

```
   echo CHtml::ajaxLink('Submit', Yii::app()->createUrl('controller/action'),
    array(
       'type'=>'POST',
       'data'=>'js:{ids : $.fn.yiiGridView.getChecked("grid-id","check-boxes")}'
    ));
```

but the nothing happen when i use this.

how we should pass the value in controller and how the controller works?

thank you.

Comment: "nothing happen"? Does a request get submitted? What parameters does it give?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10083616/submit-cgridview-checked-values-using-a-form

Answer (score 0):

```
public function actionActionName()
{

    if(isset($_POST['check-boxes'])){
        foreach ($_POST['check-boxes'] as $id){
            $model = $this->loadModel($id);
            CVarDumper::dump($id, 5, true);
        }
    }
    else
    CVarDumper::dump('Nothing is selected', 5, true);
}
```

Comment: Please consider adding an explanation also to the answer. That will make the answer more informative and useful to future readers.